# Replacing Class name after using after()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to change the class name from `<tr>`?

For example:

This will get hidden `tr` from the table.

```
var templateTR = $("item-row-template");
```

I want to add `templateTR` at the bottom of `<table>`:

```
$('table tr:last').after(templateTR);
```

Once it has been added at the end of the table, it need to replace "item-row-template" to `item-row`? or what is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing the class selector a dot:

```
var templateTR = $("item-row-template");
// here ----------^^
```

And to replace the class after appending:

```
$('table tr:last').after(templateTR);
$('.item-row-template').removeClass('item-row-template').addClass('item-row');
```

Comment: Ah, my mistake, thanks.  But It only should change the `.item-row-template` class name at the bottom of the table when it has been added.  `.item-row-template` is always there in the table for new TR creation later.

Comment: `$('table tr:last').after(templateTR).removeClass('item-row-template').addClass('item-row');` ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `item-row-template` is a class name:

```
$('.item-row-template').removeClass('item-row-template').addClass('item-row');
```